# What are "actions" in Vaadin 14?

Tags: user-interface, vaadin, action, vaadin-flow

In Vaadin 14, while looking at the `Login` component, specifically the source code for [`AbstractLogin.java`](https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-login-flow/blob/master/vaadin-login-flow/src/main/java/com/vaadin/flow/component/login/AbstractLogin.java), I noticed:

- An "action" can be saved on a login widget via `getElement.setProperty`.
- The Javadoc for `AbstractLogin::setAction` says: “Once action is defined a {@link AbstractLogin.LoginEvent} is not fired anymore.”

I understand making an object of mine a listener for `LoginEvent` by registering with the login widget via `AbstractLogin::addLoginListener`.

But this “action” seems to be an alternative way to work instead of event listeners.

Can someone tell me more about *actions* and how they work in Vaadin Flow?

I searched the [Vaadin Docs](https://vaadin.com/docs/index.html) for the word *action* but found nothing there.

Answer (score 2):

The [HTML API of the LoginForm](https://vaadin.com/components/vaadin-login/html-api/elements/Vaadin.LoginFormElement) specifies the following

> **action**: string | null | undefined= null *notify*
>
> If set, a synchronous POST call will be fired to the path defined. The
>   login event is also dispatched, so `event.preventDefault()` can be
>   called to prevent the POST call.

I understand that, with this option you can configure the login form to post the data login processing or e.g. to external authentication service. Useful use case is to set it "login" when using Vaadin with Spring security. This case is shown in [Bakery App Starter](https://vaadin.com/start/latest/full-stack-spring).

Comment: So how would I as the Vaadin web app learn the results of that external POST call, to know if the user has passed authentication?

Comment: @BasilBourque Typically the Vaadin web app wouldn't know it as such, but it would be caught by a servlet filter (often through Spring Security, Shiro, or a similar library)

Answer (score 1):

Love how they give you almost zero information. There should at least be a few breadcrumbs on [the LoginForm page](https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/components/login).

The phrase "action" here has nothing to do with Java events. Instead, it refers to [the `"action"` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data#the_action_attribute) of the HTML `<form>` tag, i.e., where the browser should POST the form data.

Review how Spring Security's Form Login works [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/passwords/form.html). It's default URI path for posting the username and password is `/login`. That's why `setAction("login")` works.